# how to add script inside a <?php ?> code?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I add script inside a php code?
I want add this script to header wordpress. Please help me. Thank alot!

```html
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push ({
    'dynx_itemid' : '<?php echo $product->get_id(); ?>',
    'dynx_pagetype' : '<?php echo $product->get_title(); ?>',
    'dynx_totalvalue' : '<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_display_price()); ?>',
    'ecomm_pagetype': '<?php echo $product->get_title(); ?>',
    'ecomm_prodid': '<?php echo $product->get_id(); ?>',
    'ecomm_totalvalue': '<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_display_price()); ?>'
});
</script>
```

I want to add script to php below : get_header( 'shop' );
My header file :

```js
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
get_header( 'shop' );

do_action('flatsome_before_product_page');
?>
```

Comment: Javascript can be added to your header in several ways [How to Easily Add JavaScript in WordPress Pages or Posts (3 Methods)](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-easily-add-javascript-in-wordpress-pages-or-posts/). 
However, your code will not work on every page as it is assumed that `$product` is defined. 
For this you will have to add an extra check, for example with [Conditional Tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Comment: Thank you, i try to user this way, but my code is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exactly what do you mean by adding script but:

```
echo '<script> //js code </script>'
```

will run your js code when page(html) has opened in browser.

Comment: thank for reply, i want to add scrip to php below :
get_header( 'shop' );